# How to do a table look up so that my dropdownlist will display the data that I want

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, drop-down-menu, lookup-tables

I have two tables called facility and Facilitytype_lookup table with relationship with each other using fac_type column field. In the first drop down list I populate the data using fac_type field on facility table, and if the selected fac_type field value is selected, for example selecting LT, the fac_code belonging to that fac_type will be displayed on the second drop down list which is L.337 and L.338 like in the screenshots. The problem is I want the first dropdownlist names to be in full. For etc MR as Meeting Room, DR as discussion Room, LT for leture Theatre. That';s why I created another table called Facilitytype_lookup with the column field called fac_name. How do I make the first drop down list names to be in full names using column field fac_name??

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
public partial class MainMenu : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            //string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["serverConnectionString"].ToString(); // connection string
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["projectConnectionString"].ToString();
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
            con.Open();


            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select distinct FAC_TYPE from FACILITY", con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);  // fill dataset

            ddlFacilityType.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["FAC_TYPE"].ToString(); // text field name of table dispalyed in dropdown
            // to retrive specific  textfield name 
            ddlFacilityType.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];      //assigning datasource to the dropdownlist
            ddlFacilityType.DataBind();  //binding dropdownlist

            ddlFacilityType.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(" Select type", "0"));
        }

        ddlFacility.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(" Select room", "0"));
    }


    protected void ddlFacilityType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["serverConnectionString"].ToString(); // connection string
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["projectConnectionString"].ToString();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        con.Open();


        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select distinct FAC_CODE from FACILITY where FAC_TYPE='" + ddlFacilityType.SelectedValue.ToString() + "'", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);  // fill dataset

        ddlFacility.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["FAC_CODE"].ToString(); // text field name of table dispalyed in dropdown
        // to retrive specific  textfield name 
        ddlFacility.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];      //assigning datasource to the dropdownlist
        ddlFacility.DataBind();  //binding dropdownlist

        ddlFacility.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(" Select room", "0"));
    }

    protected void ddlFacility_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["roomvalue"] = ddlFacility.SelectedValue;

        if (ddlFacilityType.Text == "MR")
        {
            Response.Redirect("number1.aspx");
        }
        else if (ddlFacilityType.Text == "DR")
        {
            Response.Redirect("number1.aspx");
        }
        else
            Response.Redirect("number2.aspx");       
    }
}
```

Edited, first dropdownlist will display fac_name values, but after choosing any option in first drop down list, second drop down list doesn't come out anything

```
public partial class MainMenu : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            //string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["serverConnectionString"].ToString(); // connection string
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["projectConnectionString"].ToString();
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
            con.Open();


            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select distinct facility.FAC_TYPE, facilitytype_lookup.fac_name from FACILITY inner join facilitytype_lookup ON facility.fac_type=facilitytype_lookup.fac_type", con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);  // fill dataset

            ddlFacilityType.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["FAC_name"].ToString(); // text field name of table dispalyed in dropdown

            // to retrive specific  textfield name 
            ddlFacilityType.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];      //assigning datasource to the dropdownlist
            ddlFacilityType.DataBind();  //binding dropdownlist

            ddlFacilityType.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(" Select type", "0"));
        }

        ddlFacility.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(" Select room", "0"));
    }


    protected void ddlFacilityType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["serverConnectionString"].ToString(); // connection string
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["projectConnectionString"].ToString();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        con.Open();


        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select distinct FAC_CODE from FACILITY where FAC_TYPE='" + ddlFacilityType.SelectedValue.ToString() + "'", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);  // fill dataset

        ddlFacility.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["FAC_CODE"].ToString(); // text field name of table dispalyed in dropdown
        // to retrive specific  textfield name 
        ddlFacility.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];      //assigning datasource to the dropdownlist
        ddlFacility.DataBind();  //binding dropdownlist

        ddlFacility.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(" Select room", "0"));
    }

    protected void ddlFacility_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["roomvalue"] = ddlFacility.SelectedValue;

        if (ddlFacilityType.Text == "MR")
        {
            Response.Redirect("number1.aspx");
        }
        else if (ddlFacilityType.Text == "CR")
        {
            Response.Redirect("number1.aspx");
        }
        else if (ddlFacilityType.Text == "DR")
        {
            Response.Redirect("number1.aspx");
        }
        else
            Response.Redirect("number2.aspx");

    }
}
```

Comment: change your queries. using a `Join` can be an option

Comment: Edited, first dropdownlist will display fac_name values, but after choosing any option in first drop down list, second drop down list doesn't come out anything.  @lnanikian

Comment: Update also the second query to pass `FAC_TYPE` instead of the new value

Comment: You mean for protected void ddlFacilityType_SelectedIndexChanged query, that instead of fac_code, change to fac_type? I thought I want the second drop down list to display fac_code @lnanikian

Comment: with your update this request `SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select distinct FAC_CODE from FACILITY where FAC_TYPE='" + ddlFacilityType.SelectedValue.ToString() + "'", con);` will rettun an empty list

Comment: So change to this? SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select distinct FAC_TYPE from FACILITY where FAC_TYPE='" + ddlFacilityType.SelectedValue.ToString() + "'", con); but I wan fac_code @lnanikian

Comment: just this ` ddlFacilityType.SelectedValue.ToString()`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51036/discussion-between-jordjmax-and-lnanikian)